# How do i enable the service menu programmatically with out the user log out then enable it in the keyboard preferences?

Tags: cocoa, service

As the title tells,please help...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to include the NSRequiredContext key in each of your services' dictionaries.

[The documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/SysServices/) doesn't mention this, but it is required since Mac OS X 10.6; as you've seen, your service will be disabled by default if you don't have it.

You should also call [the `NSUpdateDynamicServices` function](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Miscellaneous/AppKit_Functions/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/NSUpdateDynamicServices) on launch, to refresh the user's Services menu without them having to log out and back in.